# How can I swipe left and right using Jquery so that the line under tab can move ? For mobile https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

I want to use the link provided in my application for mobile. 
When I swipe left or right I want it to change the line under to another heading.

Comment: It already changes the line to another heading, on mobile when swiping left and right. Edit: if you're on codepen with 0.5x . It doesn't work when on the full page.

Comment: use on swipe event `$("element").on("swipe",function(){
  //Action
});`

Comment: doesnt work on mobile

Answer (score 0):

use on swipe event `$("element").on("swipe",function(){ //Action });`